# Cannot log in to gerrit with HTTP apache server authorization

Tags: mysql, apache, gerrit

I'm trying to configure own gerrit server with HTTP authorization. The APACHE server works in reverse proxy mode. In order to setup whole system I've followed tutorial from below url:

http://hacklog.tumblr.com/post/104627701707/gerrit-apache-reverse-proxy-http-auth-with-anon

Before gerrit installation I've installed mysql data base and I've added user to the database as it's suggested in url:

https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.9.2/install.html

Here is also my apache-gerrit.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location /gerrit/login/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
        Require valid-user
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
    </Location>

    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/gerrit/ nocanon

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The next file is my gerrit.conf file :

```
[gerrit]
    basePath = git
    canonicalWebUrl = http://192.168.1.3/gerrit/
[database]
    type = mysql
    hostname = localhost
    database = reviewdb
    username = gerrit2
[index]
    type = LUCENE
[auth]
    type = HTTP
    loginUrl = http://192.168.1.3/gerrit/login/
[sendemail]
    smtpServer = localhost
[container]
    user = gerrit2
    javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
    listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-http://localhost:8081/gerrit/
[cache]
    directory = cache
```

The problem is when I'm trying to log in to gerrit server I'm getting internal server errors.

[image]

After receiving few of those I'm logged in as Anonymous Coward, and later I receive more internal server errors when I'm trying to log out.

[image]

I'd be grateful if anyone could advise me where should I search for problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove "loginUrl". This is only used if you use a "special" login handling. It is okay when you get "Anonymous Coward" - you just need to set your name in settings. I think it would also help if you check (error-)logs: logs/error_log.

Comment: hello, after removing loginUrl and setting name, I'm always logged in with my name. But still I think I'm not logged in as administrator .

Comment: The first ever registered user user is only administrator by default. So you either can run Gerrit setup again with a clean database or manually try to add the administrator role to your account in the database.

Comment: ok, so in my case the first user will be user which is stored under my /etc/apache2/passwords or am I wrong ?

Comment: No, the first user you have tried to log in. It should have Account ID 1000000 (you can check in settings -> profile screen).

Comment: Currently my user ID has Account ID 1, in identities I got identity for 'gerrit2' which is name of user stored in /etc/apache2/passwords in groups I can see : Anonymous Users, Registered Users, userid/MY_NAME

Comment: Check out this help (especially last part of message): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/FkIPsL28OXM/OBJvKaMh-wgJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71988/discussion-between-lazureus-and-uwolfer).